# Is duplicating data in SQL and Document store (like MongoDB) a legit idea or should be avoided?

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

I have a question. I am considering using a data store for some type of objects (e.g. products data). Criteria for using document store is if object has a detail page, so fast read of the entire object is necessary (example - product with all attributes, images, comments etc). Criteria for using SQL is displaying lists (e.g. N newest, most popular etc).

Some objects meet both criteria. Products is an example. So is it a normal practice to store info that will be used in rendering lists on index pages in SQL database, and other data in document store?

Comment: "Criteria for using SQL is displaying lists (e.g. N newest, most popular etc). " --- you can perform all of these using mongodb. And requests will be fast if you have proper indexes and your queries were written well.

Comment: But with a lot of data even with indexes such queries should be faster on an RDBMS than on a document store, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main idea is mongoDB was created for denormalization and embedding.** At one of my past projects i've done sql denormalization to get better performance, but i don't like sql denormalization because very many dublicated data( if you have one to many relation for example). Second step was rewriting data access layer to mongoDB. And in mongoDB for some difficult pages where i need to load multiple documents i've created denormalized document(with embeded collections and plain data from different documents) to fit page content. No all my problem pages work fast, like facebook ;).

But here possible problems, becase you should support denormalized document every time. Also all my denormalized data updates work async, and some data can be stale in some moment, but it's normal practice. Even stackoverlow use denormalization because sometime when open question i see an answer, but when i return back to questions list and refresh page sometimes question doesn't have answer.

**If i need denormalization i choose mongodb.**

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Re. Stackoverflow, I think it's more of a caching problem than update of denormalized data.

Answer (score 3):

If denormalization is suitable for getting performance, go ahead with denormalization. But you have to ensure that you have a way to deal with updates of denormalized data. Your options in MongoDB are:

- multiple queries to avoid denormalization
- embedded docs
- database references

make your choice..